# How to refresh results on a searchbar in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: listview, titanium, appcelerator, searchbar

Im using Titanium Studio from Appcelerator to write an iOS/Android app. I have a standard ListView with a standard searchBar on it. While the search results are visible, I need to be able to update the ListView items. This works fine most of the time, but often enough, the results do not update. If an item was deleted, it is still visible on the search results. I believe the best way to handle this is to refresh the results of the search every time I update the ListView, but I cant seem to figure out how. Please assist.

Comment: have you tried to use it on a tableView?

Comment: Easiest way is to empty the listview and add the data again.

Answer (score 0):

List view is designed for performance. One side effect of the design is that you cannot directly manipulate the views--add children, set view properties and bind event callbacks--as you can in TableView. Instead, you interact with list items indirectly, using templates and data items.

An alternative to easily manipulate the data is to use a tableView. E.g :

```
var data = [];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    data: data,
    separatorInsets: {left: 0, right: 0}
});

var searchBar = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
    barColor:'#000', 
    showCancel:true,
    height:43,
    top:0,
});

// Add search bar how ever you want... eg, table.search = searchBar; 

table.setSearch(searchBar)

searchBar.addEventListener("return", function (e) {
    // Do API call etc
    var foo = "bar";

    data.push(foo);

    table.setData(data);
});

table.addEventListener('delete', function(e) {

    // Adjust data to delete from the data array.

    data.pop();

    table.setData(data);
});
```

You can go further and add sections with individual rows and modify these independently and tailor it to your needs.

Comment: I am unable to use a tableview, since it is too slow given the amount of data I need to present. Besides, updating the data is not my issue. I can update the list view no problem, but if I update the list view while searching, the search view doesnt always update. (If an item was deleted, it is still visible on the search view.) I imagine I need to blur the search bar, update, and then research for the same value programatically, but I cant get this to work.